# Facebook "FB.Canvas.getPageInfo", how to use it properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-canvas, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need help figuring out how to appropriately use the `FB.Canvas.getPageInfo` from Facebook's javascript sdk:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.getPageInfo/

I'm able to get the info and log/alert the data:

```
function getFbCanvasInfo() {
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(fbCanvasInfoObject) {
    console.log(fbCanvasInfoObject);
    });
}

$("a.GetScrollTest").live( "click", function() {
    getFbCanvasInfo();
    return false;
});
```

But I can't figure out how to set that data and then apply it to other elements or functions (i.e. like something below):

```
$("a#test-link").each(function() {
    var fbPosition = getFbCanvasInfo().scrollTop;
    $(this).append("<em>The scroll top value is " + fbPosition + "px");
}
```

I know its not right and I'm missing something here.

BTW these functions are all below my async init and FB root, which appears like so:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">//<!--
    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
        {
        FB.init({
            appId: '223615011031939',
            status: true, 
            cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true, 
            oauth:true, 
            channelUrl: '[MY PROJECTS CHANNEL URL]' 
        });
        var isLoaded = true;FB.Canvas.setSize();FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(500);            
        };

        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());

        ;(function($){
            $(document).ready(function($){
                [THE JQUERY FROM ABOVE HERE]
            });
        })(jQuery);
    //--></script>
```

Much appreciation to anyone who has advice/expertise!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getPageInfo` returns a readonly object.  To "set" things, you would need to use the provided setter functions listed in the documentation.  One of them to set the size of the canvas is `setSize` see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/

Also you should cleanup your javascript so the async nature of working with their API is good.

```
$("a.GetScrollTest").live( "click", function() {
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(fbCanvasInfoObject) {
        var fbPosition = fbCanvasInfoObject.scrollTop;
        $(this).append("<em>The scroll top value is " + fbPosition + "px");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I meant to get the current scrollTop value for example, and setting it as a variable to use in another jquery function...

Comment: The facebook objects are not jQuery objects.  Also your javascript code's function getFbCanvasInfo() does not return anything.  Since they're async calls, you should use something more like this:

Comment: OK thanks.  Ultimately, I'm trying to get the value of the scrollTop and add it to a static value (100px), like so: http://jsfiddle.net/b3HHv/ -- In this case its a fancybox call, but when I place the FB.Canvas code inside the .each(), it returns "FB not defined" in the console...  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hey DMCSS, could I get you to help me out, possibly for a PayPal donation?  I need to figure out why your example (http://jsfiddle.net/LntkP/) works, yet it doesn't in a .each(), like this (http://jsfiddle.net/KNNAP/).  It returns a Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined...  Email me at luke[at]filmdemic.com if you're interested.  Thanks!

Comment: Let's keep this friendly...developer to developer.  No donation required.  :)  All I ask is that if I answered your question, give me the credit by accepting my answer.  :D

Comment: I will but are you unwilling to help at all?  Why doesn't it work when I place it in an .each()?  http://jsfiddle.net/w2JRk/? A simple question and I'll accept your answer...  Thank you...

Comment: I've already answered your original question.  If you're not willing to play nice, I'm not answering anymore of your additional questions!!

Comment: Please ask your new question in a new question, rather than in the comments of this old question.  Thanks  :)